# Unable to start MySQL server on MacOS

Tags: mysql

I am following a video tutorial on Udemy about setting up and running MySQL server. The image below illustrates my current directory and the error I am getting.

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BtKU7.png)

Additional Details:

1) Operating System: OS X 10.11.6 El Capitan

2) I have only one installation of MySQL.

3) I executed "export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=..." already

4) I tried changing ownership of the mysql folder to both mysql and root, but neither measure worked out.

Comment: Which software you are using for server?

Comment: please view content in /usr/local/mysql/data/Stevens-MBP.lan.err

Comment: @kext. I tried running sudo cat /usr/local/mysql/data/Stevens-MBP.lan.err. The terminal said that this file doesn't exist :( .

Comment: @RAVIPATEL. I didn't really install another web server yet. I simply trying to run the DB server stand-alone currently. I am planning to build something with Java, so I guess Apache ??

Comment: @UniversalThinker Maybe your MySQL version is not correct, you can try to reinstall MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone who gave suggestions. I found other people struggling with the same issue who also are using a OSX 10.11 - loaded laptop.

There is a forum post about it here:
https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?11,646207,646207#msg-646207

I ended up installing an older version of MySQL via homebrew:

brew install mysql@5.6

and it worked out fine.